# Maya: Python: How to open arnoldRenderView in the script editor

Tags: python, scripting, maya

I am stuck on the Arnold's Python command list.
For this current exercise, I need to make a light-painter (e.g. https://evermotion.org/articles/show/8837/light-painter-1-0) in Maya.

I need to make it so that the ArnoldRenderView opens up automatically.
I have been searching for this quite a while now.
All I have been able to find is this: "`from mtoa.cmds.arnoldRenderView import arnoldRenderView`".

Where can I find what flags I can use to make the ArnoldRenderView open up (by a button click)?

Or is there a more simple way to open up the ArnoldRenderView without accessing the "`mtoa.cmds.arnoldRenderView`"?

With Kind Regards,
Rik.

**EDIT:**
I have found two helpfull links with scripting in maya (Python) for arnold:
https://arnoldsupport.com/2015/03/04/arnold-getting-started-with-the-arnold-python-api/
and https://trac.solidangle.com/arnoldpedia/chrome/site/Arnold-4.1.3.3/doc/api/index.html

Comment: It should help to have a look at the way Arnold itself executes it. Have a look at your MtoA directory: `C:\solidangle\MtoADeploy\2018\scripts\mtoa\ui\arnoldmenu.py`. There you will find the command which is executed if you select the menu item, what indeed seems to be cmds.arnoldRenderView(). And since `arnoldRenderView`is a plugin command you should be able to get any commandline options with help(cmds.arnoldRenderView).

Comment: Thanks for the information, I didn't know it was possible to acces this kind of file. I will check it out to see if I can find a solution to my problem. If I find something I'll let you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer to my problem.

```
# import libraries (Maya Commands Library and mtoa Core Library)
import maya.cmds as cmds
import mtoa.core as core
```

Like haggi krey said, you'll find the necessary functions in the `arnoldmenu.py` file

```
#Copy paste both functions from the arnoldmenu.py Script (filepath: "C:\solidangle\mtoadeploy\2018\scripts\mtoa\ui\arnoldmenu.py")
def arnoldOpenMtoARenderView():
    core.createOptions()
    cmds.arnoldRenderView(mode ="open")

def arnoldMtoARenderView():
    # core.ACTIVE_CAMERA is not set, anything we could do here ?
    #if core.ACTIVE_CAMERA != None:
    #    cmds.arnoldRenderView(cam=core.ACTIVE_CAMERA)
    # so instead we're calling it without any argument
    core.createOptions()
    cmds.arnoldRenderView()

#execute both functions
arnoldOpenMtoARenderView()
arnoldMtoARenderView()
```

This script opens up the arnoldRenderView in same state as you last closed it.